# Firebase GithubAuthProvider signInWithPopup responds with auth/admin-restricted-operation

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

### Summary

I think I have a pretty simple setup, but I can't seem to sign-up using the GitHub auth provider for Firebase. Every time I try, it loads the popup fine, I click the authorize button, it does some thinking, and then ultimately response with `FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation).`

### Steps in more detail

#### 1 - Vue3 component

```
<template>
...
  <button @click="signUpWithGitHub()">Sign Up</button>
...
</template>

<script setup>
import { getAuth, GithubAuthProvider, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";

async function signUpWithGitHub() {
  const provider = new GithubAuthProvider();
  const result = await signInWithPopup(getAuth(), provider);
}
</script>
```

#### 2 - GitHub Config

I've created an OAuth app in GitHub under my organization. This seemed very straightforward.

#### 3 - Firebase Config

Under the Authentication section for my Firebase project, on the *Sign-in method* tab, I added a GitHub provider.

For *Client ID* and *Client secret*, I entered the values obtained from my GitHub config above. The provider is enabled. I took the callback URL from this page and entered it back on the GitHub config for the *Authorization callback URL*.

Still all very straightforward...

#### 4 - The process

1. Click the button defined above
2. Popup loads, as expected, thanks for Firebase working its magic
3. Popup asks for me to authorize the app
4. I click *Authorize*
5. It does some processing and the popup goes away
6. I check the console in Chrome DevTools and see the error mentioned in the summary above

At this point, GitHub recognizes that there is one user associated to the GitHub OAuth app. Firebase does not recognize that there are any users.

So it's failing after successfully authorizing with GitHub and before successfully linking everything up to Firebase.

--

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to initialize the app with firebaseConfig, try this:

```
<template>
...
  <button @click="signUpWithGitHub()">Sign Up</button>
...
</template>

<script setup>
import { getAuth, GithubAuthProvider, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
// find yours in SDK setup and configuration
}

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const provider = new GithubAuthProvider();
const auth = getAuth();

async function signUpWithGitHub(auth, provider) {
  const result = await signInWithPopup();
}
</script>
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/github-auth
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: I don't remember what I did, but I think I don't have this issue anymore. If I had to guess, I believe that I just blew up the original Firebase project and started a new one... easy to do since it was a prototype application, and not very helpful to the community.